# How to calculate pseudo-determinant for implementing Naive-Bayes

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, determinant, bayesian, bayes-theorem

(People who followed `Bayesian` tag, please read the third paragraph)

Problem: I need to calculate pseudo-determinant of a matrix (preferably in MATLAB, but no built-in function is available. I can write one). I see two different methods to calculate pseudo-determinants. One from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant) and one from [Maple online help page](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/Determinant) - search for `ipseudo` - I don't use Maple but I tried to read that method and I couldn't understand it.

Wikipedia method (the first equation on that page) is easy to implement but I am unsure about its correctness. Essentially, I tried to find the lowest `alpha` which makes $det(A+\alpha*I)$ non-zero. This method gives determinant values which are: 4e-11 and 5e+14. As I change the definition of `tending to zero` (i.e. I was using `if determinant>1e-10 or >1e-100` etc.), the values jump from 4e-11 and 5e+14. So I am pretty sure its not correct. Anybody knows how to calculate pseudo-determinant of `200x200` matrix?

Interested people can read further. I want to give background to this problem as to why I am calculating pseudo-determinant and want to take your opinion on is this even necessary?

I want to use Bayes' theorem and caluclate likelihood. Since my feature space is 200 dimensional, I decided to use multivariate Gaussian distribution [(MVN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). I calculate covariance matrix and then find out that it is singular. So I read further on that page and come across a `Degenerate case` which handles singular covariance matrices. That's where I am told to calculate pseudo-determinant of the matrix. Is this needed? I feel it is, otherwise how to I calculate likelihood?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the covariance matrix symmetric? If so, doesn't  singular value decomposition do what you want? TO be precise, compute the SVD, and take the product of non-zero singular values.

Comment: Yes, it is symmetric. But how to calculate pseudo-determinant. I know we can calculate pseudo-inverse from SVD.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. That works. One more question. Do I have to check if the matrix is positive/negative definite/semidefinite? I observed sometimes the signs are reversed i.e. by using det and by using svd method. I guess that has to do with positive/negative definite.

Comment: The covariance matrix is ALWAYS positive semidefinite...

Comment: Oh ya. Dumb question. I knew it :)

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, because the product of non-zero singular values is 0 (practically, maybe it is less than 1e-308). Now, if I decide to take product of only those elements greater than 1e-3, product comes out 4e-36, and if greater than 1e-2, then product comes out to be 1e+21. So the problem persists. This problem was there even when I calculated by using wikipedia method i.e. using $\alpha$

Comment: @Autonomous people like to use log determinants instead for this reason (sum the log nonzero eigenvals).